# How to fix installation error of missing dependencies (libmysqlclient_16) for Sphinx search 2.2.10 on RedHat/Centos 6.7 in cPanel/WHM

Tags: centos, sphinx

On my VPS mediatemple server with cPanel/whm, I've tried every which way installing Sphinx with yum as well as doing rpm -Uvc with a local download.

And it always returns these errors:

Error: Package: sphinx-2.2.10-1.rhel6.i386 (/sphinx-2.2.10-1.rhel6.i386)
Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)
Error: Package: sphinx-2.2.10-1.rhel6.i386 (/sphinx-2.2.10-1.rhel6.i386)
Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16

I can see that I have these files are located at /usr/lib64/libmysqlclient.so.16, but it keeps throwing this error. I read that I was missing MySQL-community-libs-compat files, I tried but MySQL installation is handled through cpanel and got conflicting notices.

I had previously installed Sphinx 2.2.9 wiht no issues, and went ahead and removed it to upgrade. Now I can't install anything. No Bueno!

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?

```
yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-lib
```

Comment: Yes I have already tried this and I get 
No package mysql available.
No package mysql-devel available.
No package mysql-lib available.
Error: Nothing to do

This installation is on a server that mysql is handled by cpanel/whm. I can see the installed libraries on /usr/lib64/ folder, but for some reason it does not seem to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Always install local packages using `yum` ,  e.g. `yum local install LocalPackage.rpm`. Yum can handle package dependencies.
Remove sphinx and reinstall using `yum localinstall` .

Comment: Yes I have already tried this, and I get the same error. I evern tried installing with --skipdep but when I run Sphinx it gives the same error as before.